# How can I run `catalog.load` in a non-IPython context?

Tags: python-3.x, dataset, ipython, kedro

In IPython I can run `data = catalog.load('my_dataset')` in order to load a dataset specified as 'my_dataset' in the `catalog.yml` file. What's the equivalent command in a pthon script? What do I need to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can see how to do it here: https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/get_started/hello_kedro.html

It's also important to only use this if you're not going to violate some of Kedro's core assumptions (i.e. that nodes are functionally pure and have no idea of IO). 99% of the time, the right way to extend the life cycle of a run is via [hooks](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/hooks/examples.html).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, in your link I can see how to create a new instance of a DataCatalog. But what I want is 'the one' instance that is loaded in every IPython session, that contains all of the datasets specified in `catalog.yml`. Is there a way to instanciate that / access that?

Comment: Well the interactive workflow exposed via the IPython session is designed for prototyping, so I'd discourage you from using the code API directly since the declarative pattern detailed in the Spaceflights tutorial is the path users should follow.  It's been designed with reproducibility and maintainability in mind, having access to a live session/catalog can easily invalidate some of the core assumptions.  https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/spaceflights_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

When using kedro you don't need to load the data explicitly, just make sure the name of the input used in your pipeline definition matches the one you are using in `catalog.yml`

```
node(
    func=create_model_input_table,
    inputs=["my_dataset"],
    outputs="model_input_table",
    name="create_model_input_table_node",
),
```

You can follow tutorial in official documentation -> [create pipelines](https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/create_pipelines.html#extend-the-data-processing-pipeline)